# Custom Editor for a Boolean Property in a PropertyGrid (C#)

Tags: c#, boolean, propertygrid

I want to assign a custom editor to a `boolean` property in a `PropertyGrid`. I'm using the standard propertygrid (from namespace `System.Windows.Forms`). It is possible to assign custom editors to properties using the `UITypeEditor` class. However, as far as I can see, it is not possible to use it for a `boolean` property.

I've tried to solve it by overriding the property grid so I can add items manually. I can add a `string` property that has a custom editor by the following piece of code:

```
Properties.Item.Add("My Custom Editor", "", false, "Properties with custom UITypeEditor", "The component accept custom UITypeEditor.", true);
Properties.Item[Properties.Item.Count - 1].CustomEditor = new MyEditor();
```

So far so good, a custom editor appears (with a button in the grid). However, when I change the type to `boolean` by setting the default value on `false` (see below), the button to open the custom editor doesn't appear. Instead, a dropdown menu with `true`/`false` appears.

```
Properties.Item.Add("My Custom Editor", false, false, "Properties with custom UITypeEditor", "The component accept custom UITypeEditor.", true);
Properties.Item[Properties.Item.Count - 1].CustomEditor = new MyEditor();
```

Does anyone has a solution for this?

Thanks in forward!

Regards,
Peter

Comment: Your assumption is not correct.  Making one that's actually useful is another matter.

Comment: Do you have a pointer for me?

Comment: What leads you to say "it is not possible to use it for a boolean property"?  Have you tried it and received errors?  Is it documented somewhere that this is not possible with booleans?

Comment: @Patrick Steele Thanks for your comment. I've described the solution I've tried to the question text. I hope you can help me out!

Comment: Interesting.  I've never seen the PropertyGrid used that way.  In the past, I've just created a custom UITypeEditor and used the Editor attribute to apply it to the property in my class that will be the data source for my property grid.  I've never had to mess around with the PropertyGrid's Properties collection.

Comment: That is right, I can also do it that way. I've tried it this way just to make it easier to test some stuff. As I found out, it is not possible to use a custom editor on a boolean property. Do you (or anyone) know a solution where this can be achieved? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Microsoft PropertyGrid checks this flag to determine if it displays a dropdown arrow (flag == true) or a modal button (flag == false):

```
bool flag = gridEntryFromRow.NeedsDropDownButton | gridEntryFromRow.Enumerable;
```

The first part is true if the UITypeEditor style is DropDown and the second part is true if the attached TypeConverter's GetStandardValuesSupported returns true.

You can check all this in PropertyGridView.SelectRow in Reflector.

If you are able to attach a custom TypeConverter to your boolean (I would derive it from BooleanConverter) whose GetStandardValuesSupported method is overriden to return false, then you will get your modal button. Of course you loose the standard values (double clicking won't cycle the values for example), this is a tradeoff. I have identified this issue a long time ago and that's why in my own PropertyGrid I am not so strict and will enable a modal editor even if standard values are defined as long as I attach a ForceEditor attribute to the property.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try to implement this in my project. So, as far as I can see now, it is not possible to show both in a MS Property grid?